# How do I select an empty line in Google Docs using App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to make an add on to make underscores and (preferably) new lines red.  I would use `var line = body.findText("\nl");` or `var line = body.findText("<br>");`, but those select that bit of text and if it worked, would select every new line, empty or not.

Here's the code snippet that I copy and paste for the main parts:

```
function redLine() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var line = body.findText("");
  while (line) {
    var elem = line.getElement();
    var start = line.getStartOffset();
    var end = line.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    elem.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#FF0000");
    line = body.findText("", line);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from your question and your script. In order to correctly understand your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different answer and rewrote that section, and used this code.

```
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  var i = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
       if (paragraphs[i].getText() === ""){
          paragraphs[i].setForegroundColor("#FF0000");
       }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).